# Convert .docx to .pdf using python within Google App Engine

Tags: python, linux, google-app-engine

I am trying to convert a .docx file i have in my **/tmp** directory to .pdf using python within Google App Engine. I have used **docx2pdf** before, but google app engine or Linux doesnt support this module. I have seen people use **Libreoffice** to convert the file, but i dont know how to **install Libreoffice** within Google app engine. I could really use some help.

Comment: Google App Engine Standard does not allow installing packages. Maybe you may want to try with App Engine Flex which uses containers so you can use what you need there, possibly even docx2pdf

Comment: thanks for responding, i will give the flex environment a go

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to install 3rd party tools or binaries, you could try using App Engine Flex, this is because in the Google App Engine Standard runtime is not possible to install packages.

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments#compare_high-level_features) you can see more differences between the Standard and Flexible environment. In a few words, Standard is a sandbox were you are only responsible about the code, and in Flexible you have the power of containers to configure the environment through a Dockerfile.

Comment: thank you! i will take a look at the flex environment! :)

Comment: I have a question...i am really new to the world of tech and python....when i create my dockerfile....is this where i have to specify the module i want? or does this still go in the requirements file?

Comment: I'd recommend to create a new questions since this one is not related at all with the original one. Anyway, I'd say that before using App Engine, first understand how Docker works and try some samples and search on your own. Once you've completely understood how Docker works and make it work with a Python App you can then go with App Engine or any other products.

Comment: got it :) thanks!

Comment: the new problem that i have is that with just a simple hello world deploy, the flex environment charged me 4 dollars :( and my company doesnt aprove any additional costs :( Someone recomended me that another alternative is to send the doc to Drive and download it as a pdf....hopefully this works